# Why am I not receiving a 60 MHz signal from CLKOUT in sync.FIFO mode on the FT2232H?

Tags: ftdi, labview

I tried to set sync.FIFO mode on FT2232H.

[image]

According to paragraph 4 (pg.10) of AN_130 (FT2232H Used in an FT245 Style Synchronous FIFO Mode) I expected a 60MHz signal at pin No.32 (CLKOUT) after set sync.FIFO mode. But there was no any signal.

[image]

I also tried to use MSSP mode to make sure the quality of the solder CLKOUT pin.

[image]

The solder quality is good.

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT2232H.pdf give the impression that one either needs an EEPROM for sync FIFO or can configurate it via software. But https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/TechnicalNotes/TN_167_FIFO_Basics.pdf states that both are actually required and that the right setting has to be set e.g. vias FT_PROG. Please check if this is the case.